# Set inclusion for reals

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-number-theory

> Statement: $K \subset \mathbb R$ is compact implies $K$ is closed.

> Proof: Suppose $K$ is compact. Consider the collection of open sets $\displaystyle{O_{k_{\in \mathbb N}} = \left\{x \in \mathbb R: |x - a| > \frac 1k\right\}}$. Then $\color{green}{\displaystyle{\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty O_k = \mathbb R \setminus \{a\}}}$ and so $\displaystyle{K \subset\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty O_k}$. Since $K$ is compact, $\displaystyle{K \subset\bigcup_{j=1}^m O_{k_j}}$. Let $N = \max\{k_i\}_{i=1}^m$. Then $\displaystyle{K \subset\bigcup_{j=1}^m O_{k_j} = \left\{x \in \mathbb R: |x - a| > \frac 1N\right\}}$. By taking complements, we have $\displaystyle{\left\{x \in \mathbb R: |x - a| < \frac 1N\right\} \subset \left\{x \in \mathbb R: |x - a| \color{red}{\le} \frac 1N\right\} \color{blue}{\subset} K^c}$ meaning $a$ is an interior point of $K^c$ implying $K^c$ is open which to say $K$ is closed.

I'd like to prove the relations in $\color{green}{\text{green}}$ and $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ and give a reason for the one in $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ above. Please, see if what I typed below works. Thanks.

---

Statement: $\color{green}{\displaystyle{\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty O_k = \mathbb R \setminus\{a\}}}$.

Proof:

Note, $a \not \in O_k$  because $|a - a| \not > \frac 1k$ for any $k$.

Suppose $\displaystyle{x \in \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty O_k}$. Then $x \in O_k$ for some $k$ and so $x \in \mathbb R \setminus \{a\}$ by definition of $O_k$. Now assume $x \in \mathbb R \setminus \{a\}$. By Archimedes, there's some $K \in \mathbb N$ s.t. $\displaystyle{K > \frac{1}{|x - a|} \iff \frac 1K < |x - a|}$ and so $x \in O_K$ meaning $\displaystyle{x \in \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty O_k}$.

---

Statement: $\color{blue}{\displaystyle{\left\{x \in \mathbb R: |x - a| \le \frac 1N \right\} \subset K^c.}}$

Proof:

Since $K \subset \mathbb R$, we have that $K^c = \mathbb R \setminus K.$ Suppose $\displaystyle{s \in \left\{x \in \mathbb R: |x - a| \le \frac 1N \right\}}$. Then $\displaystyle{|s - a| \le \frac 1N}$. Since $\displaystyle{K \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^mO_{k_j}}$, every element $t \in K$ has the property $\displaystyle{|t - a| > \frac 1k}$ and so $s \ne t$ meaning $s \not \in K$ implying $s \in K^c$.

---

We need $\displaystyle{\left\{x \in \mathbb R: |x - a| \le \frac 1N \right\} \subset K^c}$ instead of $\displaystyle{\left\{x \in \mathbb R: |x - a| < \frac 1N \right\} \subset K^c}$ because $O_k^c = \displaystyle{\left\{x \in \mathbb R: |x - a| \le \frac 1k \right\}}$ by trichotomy law for reals.